# Deployment of docker images

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a docker image. Whenever I run the container, I need to provide input files externally to the container and then some commands. So, if I am deploying that image to kubernetes, then how I am supposed to provide data if it is continuously running. Any leads will be appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful if your would be a bit more specific, eg if you already know how to start your container with `docker run`, then this command would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In Kubernetes a pod is a group of one or more containers (such as Docker containers), with shared storage/network, and a specification for how to run the containers.

You can pass any kind of meta-data to the container using the Kubernetes deployment scripts. [Check out this link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/) for a sample.

Whenever the pods (containers) are restarted, the parameters are automatically passed by the pod specification yaml file.